# Simple document highlighting in Vim

Tags: vim, text-editors, text-formatting, highlighting, filetype

I am looking for a *filetype=* argument that will format or color document
constructs such as lists, headers and sub headrs.

Particularly I want the filetype plugin (or syntax plugin) to interpret 
these formats:

```
Header
======

Sub
---

Sub2
----


[*] moo
[*] foo
[*] bar
```

Comment: Is this a format you've come up with, or an existing one? If it's an existing one, it probably already has a plugin for Vim; just search http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php for the name of the markup language. If not, you can probably take an existing language (such as Markdown) and adapt its plugin fairly easily.

Comment: @echristopherson I'm looking for "markdown". Thank you.

Comment: Then you can just `:set ft=markdown`. However, `[*]` is not part of Markdown proper; you can use `+` or `-` or `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown is sufficient enough or applying basic styles and formatting to plain-text documents.

Answer (score -1):

What you probably want is to use [syntax highlighting](http://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/vi/vi-4.shtml).

Check out the [vbnet.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1525) plugin to see a more complex ***example*** of a syntax file than is shown in the tutorial. You'll need to create your own syntax file to handle the custom formats you show in your question. You would do this by setting up various `keyword`, `match`, `cluster`, and `region` groups to get what you want. ***Examples*** of how to set up each of these groups can be found in the vbnet.vim plugin.

Once you've written your own custom syntax file, then assign those syntax groups a name as seen in the last line of vbnet.vim:

```
let b:current_syntax = "vbnet"
```

And in your .vimrc use an `autocmd` to turn on that specific syntax highlighting for a specific file extention:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.vb set ft=vbnet
```

Adjust the highlighting of various groups in your colorscheme file.

Comment: Isn't all .net stuff C#? Why can't I simply use a C# syntax file and use :set syntax=c# (or even let it auto-detect it)? I know that I want to use syntax highlighting, but not for visual basic, because I can guess they don't use headers and lists like I _asked for in the question_. All I wanted was a name of a format.

Comment: I think the idea was to just use vbnet.vim as a point to start making a new syntax file.

Comment: @Ярослав Рахматуллин .NET is a framework that is language agnostic. But that's neither here nor there. The example formats you gave in your question are not part of any standard filetype. What I provided was a tutorial on how to set up _custom_ syntax highlighting and an _example_ of a more complex syntax file to get a feel for how to write your own. echristopherson is correct, it was meant only as a starting point. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Markdown is part of my distro's vim package. I don't know the syntax, hence the wrong [*] list elements. Headers are right, tough. Thanks for your answer.